# Lucene search: case sensitive, diacritics

Tags: java, search, lucene, hibernate-search

I'm rather new to Lucene but I would like to search on a certain field but with different options.
Let's say I have the following words:

1. Test
2. Test
3. tEst
4. test
5. tést
6. Tést

I would like to be able to search on the search value 'test' and I want the search to be case sensitive and diacritic aware. Giving me result 4.

But I would also like to be able to search on the search value 'test' and I want the search to be case insensitive and diacritic unaware. Giving me result 1-6.

Also searches like case insensitive and diacritic aware should be possible.
Just like any other combination.

What would be the best approach to handle this?

I already tried annotating my field:

```
@Fields({
      @Field(analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(impl = WhitespaceAnalyzer.class)),
      @Field(name = "DiacriticUnaware", analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "diacritics"))
  })
private String fieldToSearchIn;
```

while having this AnalyzerDef:

```
@AnalyzerDefs({
    @AnalyzerDef(name = "diacritics",
        tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class),
        filters = {
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory.class)
        })
})
```

But this only allows me to search case sensitive or case sensitive in combination with diacritic unaware.
I can create multiple indexed fields for this property but I don't know if this is the right approach because I will end up with indexing the property and storing it into 10 or more different index fields in Lucene.

Like this:

```
@Fields({
      @Field(analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(impl = WhitespaceAnalyzer.class)),
      @Field(name = "DiacriticUnaware", analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "diacritics")),
      @Field(name = "DiacriticUnawareCaseSenstitive", analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "diacriticsCaseSensitive")),
      @Field(name = "DiacriticUnawareCaseInsenstitive", analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "diacriticsCaseInsensitive")),
      @Field(name = "DiacriticAwareCaseSenstitive", analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "diacriticAwareCaseSenstitive")),
      @Field(name = "DiacriticAwareCaseInsenstitive", analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES, analyzer = @Analyzer(definition = "diacriticAwareCaseInsenstitive")),
      ...
  })
```

Comment: 10 or more?  Seems like exactly 4 would be called for to me.  Can you explain what you mean there?

Comment: For the moment I only have 2 options: diacritics, case but the options will grow, I will end up with 4 or 5 options that should be combined.

Comment: I think the right option is to work with multiple fields and target the right field(s) during query time depending on the usecase.

Comment: So the way I was showing is the right way to do it? I would have hoped there was a cleaner way to do this. Thanks!